# How to view long image in blackberry application?

Tags: blackberry

I having long image that is three times height of blackberry bold screen. when i m showing that picture in my application i cant able to view whole image.i can only see first part and last part middle part is not visible.Is there is any way to view the whole image like line by line .

Comment: how are you showing the picture?

Comment: i have used bitmapfield to show the picuture

Comment: check out class EncodedImage. 
U can save your image in this class and use scaleImage32 method to provide the dimensions to the image

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to scroll the image, try putting the BitmapField inside of a `VerticalFieldManager` created with the `Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL` style.

Comment: Something similar I guess
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916523/blackberry-background-bitmap-doesnt-fit-for-scrolling-page